# Arduino near Identical Functions with very different outputs

Tags: c, arduino

I have 3 different functions that send text messages using my Arduino and SIM900.

The first function has two arguments and sends the character array given to it to the target phone number

```
void sendText(char msg[], char num[]) {
  Serial.print("[Text] Sending text to ");
  Serial.println(num);
  simController.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  simController.print("AT + CMGS = \"");
  simController.print(num);
  simController.println("\"");
  delay(100);
  Serial.print("[Text] ");
  Serial.println(msg);
  simController.println(msg);
  delay(100);
  simController.println((char)26);
  delay(100); 
  simController.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

The last two functions are near identical except they have different number of arguments and have completely different outcomes

```
void sendText(char msg[], char num[], int startChar) {
  char *newMsg = (char *)malloc(strlen(msg)+1);
  memset(&newMsg[0], 0, sizeof(newMsg));
  Serial.print("[Text] Sending text to ");
  Serial.println(num);
  simController.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  simController.print("AT + CMGS = \"");
  simController.print(num);
  simController.println("\"");
  delay(100);
  for (int x=0;x<strlen(msg);x++) newMsg[x] = msg[x+startChar];
  Serial.print("[Text] ");
  Serial.println(newMsg);
  simController.println(newMsg);
  delay(100);
  simController.println((char)26);
  delay(100); 
  simController.println();
  delay(5000);
}

void sendText(char msg[], char num[], int startChar, int endChar) {
  char *newMsg = (char *)malloc(strlen(msg)+1);
  memset(&newMsg[0], 0, sizeof(newMsg));
  Serial.print("[Text] Sending text to ");
  Serial.println(num);
  simController.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  simController.print("AT + CMGS = \"");
  simController.print(num);
  simController.println("\"");
  delay(100);
  for (int x=0;x<strlen(msg);x++) newMsg[x] = msg[x+startChar];
  Serial.print("[Text] ");
  Serial.println(newMsg);
  simController.println(newMsg);
  delay(100);
  simController.println((char)26);
  delay(100); 
  simController.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

The code I use when calling these function looks like this

```
sendText("Hello","+447597865XXX");
sendText("Hello","+447597865XXX", 1);
sendText("Hello","+447597865XXX", 1, 3);
```

The output looks like this

```
[Text] Sending text to +447597865XXX
[Text] Hello
[Text] Sending text to +447597865XXX
[Text] ello
[Text] Sending text to +447597865XXX
[Text] ell��U�����=ڨl��fr}Ѧ�o�e�6�������f��+��V���_{���
```

Why is this happening? Remember there is no difference between the body of `void sendText(char msg[], char num[], int startChar, int endChar)` and `void sendText(char msg[], char num[], int startChar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `memset` is wrong, specifically `sizeof(newMsg)` where `newMsg` is a pointer. So `sizeof(newMsg)` is most likely 2 or 4 depending on your platform. The first one might work by luck, having already 0 in uninitialized memory.

Use the size passed to `malloc` also for `memset` (or only write the string terminator `'\0'` after you copied your data with the `for` loop.

And also check if `malloc` succeeded, i.e. it's return value is not `NULL`.

Edit: To refactor your second function, you can remove the call to `memset` and change

```
for (int x=0;x<strlen(msg);x++) newMsg[x] = msg[x+startChar];
```

to

```
int x;
for (x=0;x<strlen(msg);x++) newMsg[x] = msg[x+startChar];
newMsg[x] = '\0'; // Or just 0, it is equivalent
```